# Rails class path in application configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to configure the custom form builder in my application.rb:

```
config.action_view.default_form_builder = StandardBuilder
```

The standard form builder lives in lib directory and I pre-load it in application.rb as well:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

Yet configuring StandardBuilder can not locate the custom builder class, I guess because the initialisation hasn't been applied yet.

I've put my configuration in environment.rb post initialisation, but I think it's a hack:

```
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = StandardBuilder
```

Is there any way I can configure the path to my StandardBuilder in application.rb??

Comment: Do you mean sticking StandardBuilder file into intializers directory?

Comment: have a look https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3341